# How to make that two connection works at the same time on debian?

Tags: debian

I try to makes  working two connection on debian. One is a wired connection to a local network and one is a wireless network on internet. I have try all combinaisons that i can imagine. But result is the same.

Either I have no longer the local connection, or I have no longer the internet connection

ip route :

```
default via 192.168.43.1 dev wlan0  proto static  metric 1024 
36.65.4.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 36.65.4.105 
36.65.4.0/24 via 36.65.4.105 dev eth0  proto static  metric 1 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlan0  scope link  metric 1000 
192.168.43.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.43.139
```

Comment: can you connect to both and then run `ip route` then edit the question and add the result ?

Comment: why is the supposed "local network" (wired one) have 36.65.4.0 as IP?

Comment: it has got IP 36.65.4.105 . 36.65.4.0/24 is the netmask

Comment: you cant reach any host in the 36.65.4.0/24 subnet ?

Comment: I can reach 36.64.4.0/24 subnet but not use it DNS server.